# Android renabling listitem in listview after disabling it

Tags: android, listview, android-view, listitem, viewgroup

I have a `BaseActivity` which extends `Activity` and all the other activities extends this `BaseActivity`.

What I do is in a state of my application, I want to disable all the items on the screen from the `BaseActivity` then enable them again by using the following code:

```
private void DisableChildClickEvents(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        childView.setClickable(enabled);
        childView.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (childView instanceof ViewGroup) {
            DisableChildClickEvents((ViewGroup)childView, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I have a `ListView` in one of the activities which this code disables it and all clicks on it's items, but it can't enable clicking on them again. Which `ListItem` shows that it can be clicked and its color changes while clicking but the action that is supposed to do is not reachable after disabling them.

Comment: Not sure, did you try setting a onClickListener again? Maybe it gets unregistered if you disable clickable automatically

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I am already setting setOnItemClickListener for the ListView, why do I have to set it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (childView instanceof ListView) {
               if (enabled == true) {
                   ListView list = (ListView) childView;
                   list.getOnItemClickListener();
               }
```